# How to replace current Core Data sqlite file with a new one?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is how I setup my Core Data container and trying to replace empty one with a new one not empty:

```
init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
        let options = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        options.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption)
        options.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption)
        let containerUrl = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: SharedGroupName)!
        let url = containerUrl.appendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url), options]
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error { fatalError(error.localizedDescription) }
        }
        if let url = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url {
            let coordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
            coordinator.performAndWait {
                if let store = coordinator.persistentStores.first {
                    if let newDatabaseUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: ".sqlite") {
                        do {
                            try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store)
                            try FileManager.default.replaceItemAt(url, withItemAt: newDatabaseUrl)
                        } catch {
                            print("❌ error \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an error printed on console:

> ❌ error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “MyApp.sqlite” couldn’t be saved in the folder “11C96DDE-7820-4053-AADE-4AAE1E7F3731”." UserInfo={NSFileNewItemLocationKey=file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/02E8B158-CE4A-4D3E-97A8-A04E19ED99A2/MyApp%20Watch%20App.app/MyApp.sqlite, NSFileOriginalItemLocationKey=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/11C96DDE-7820-4053-AADE-4AAE1E7F3731/MyApp.sqlite, NSUnderlyingError=0x16da66a0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “MyApp.sqlite” in the folder “MyApp”." UserInfo={NSURLKeysOfUnsetValuesKey=(
> NSURLFileSecurityKey,
> NSURLCreationDateKey
> ), NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/02E8B158-CE4A-4D3E-97A8-A04E19ED99A2/MyApp Watch App.app/MyApp.sqlite, NSUnderlyingError=0x16d92960 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, NSURL=file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/02E8B158-CE4A-4D3E-97A8-A04E19ED99A2/MyApp%20Watch%20App.app/MyApp.sqlite}}, NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/11C96DDE-7820-4053-AADE-4AAE1E7F3731/MyApp.sqlite}

What can I do with it? Why I cannot replace sqlite file? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The application bundle is *read-only.* If you want to create a store at runtime then it must be in some of the read-write directories, such as the Documents directory.

Comment: I am not sure If I think correctly. Should I change location for initial `.sqlite` file? How can I do it to move it to Documents directory and make core data visible to the app? Additionally, I need to move the file from `Bundle.main` to original location of initial sqlite file.. and there replace it. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use it like this:

```
  if let url = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url {
        let coordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
        coordinator.performAndWait {
            if let store = coordinator.persistentStores.first {
                if let newDatabaseUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: ".sqlite") {
                    do {
                        try coordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: url, withPersistentStoreFrom: newDatabaseUrl, type: .sqlite)
                    } catch {
                        print("❌ error \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```